# How to clear textarea on click?

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

Given a `<textarea>` with a default value as follows:

```
<textarea>Please describe why</textarea>
```

How do you clear the default value when the user clicks to edit the field?

Comment: Please use real `<label>s` and don't abuse the default value to act as a fake label. Aside from being semantically rubbish, this causes a real problem for screen reader users since the only information telling them what to put in the field vanishes when the element gains the focus … and screen readers don't read out the text in a field until it gains the focus!

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Your JavaScript:

```
function clearContents(element) {
  element.value = '';
}
```

And your HTML:

```
<textarea onfocus="clearContents(this);">Please describe why</textarea>
```

I assume you'll want to make this a little more robust, so as to not wipe user input when focusing a second time. [Here](http://www.codingforums.com/archive/index.php/t-2583.html) [are](http://www.codingforums.com/archive/index.php/t-189649.html) [five](http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/help/sutra53395.html) [related](http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum91/3145.htm) [discussions](http://css-tricks.com/creating-a-nice-textarea/) & [articles](http://www.codingforums.com/archive/index.php/t-45138.html).

And here's the [(much better) idea](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp) that David Dorward refers to in comments above:

```
<label for="explanation">Please describe why</label>
<textarea name="explanation" id="explanation"></textarea>
```

Comment: The for attribute needs to match an id, not a name! (Otherwise it would be incompatible with radio buttons)

Comment: You should get rid of the `javascript:` bit. It is a label with no goto. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Statements/label If you use intrinsic event attributes then you are required to specify the language used, but this is achieved with a meta tag, not a label: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.2.1

Comment: Strange. The second idea with a `label` did not work for me.

Answer (score 41):

You can use the placeholder attribute introduced in HTML5:

```
<textarea placeholder="Please describe why"></textarea>
```

This will place your filler text in grey that will disappear automatically when a user clicks on the text field. Additionally, it will reappear if it loses focus and the text area is blank.

Comment: This is not true. It disappears when the user starts writing not on click.

Answer (score 10):

This is your javascript file:

```
function yourFunction(){
     document.getElementById('yourid').value = "";
};
```

This is the html file:

```
    <textarea id="yourid" >
    Your text inside the textarea
    </textarea>
    <button onClick="yourFunction();">
     Your button Name
     </button>
```

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
<input name="mytextbox" onfocus="if (this.value=='Please describe why') this.value = ''" type="text" value="Please Describe why">
```

Comment: This is not a textarea, so -1. This does only delete the sample text, so +1.

Answer (score 5):

Did you mean like this for textfield?

```
<input type="text" onblur="if(this.value == '') this.value='SEARCH';" onfocus="if(this.value == 'SEARCH') this.value='';" size="15" value="SEARCH" name="xSearch" id="xSearch">
```

Or this for textarea?

```
<textarea id="usermsg" rows="2" cols="70" onfocus="if(this.value == 'enter your text here') this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value == '') this.value='enter your text here';" >enter your text here</textarea>
```

Comment: My version is clearing only the default value. Dolph's solution clears everything in the textfield/textarea, not only the default value.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution what I know so far:

```
<textarea name="message" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'text here';}"   onfocus="if (this.value == 'text here') {this.value = '';}">text here</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<textarea name="post" id="post" onclick="if(this.value == 'Write Something here..............') this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value == '') this.value='Write Something here..............';" >Write Something here..............</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery attribute val() should do the job.
You can do `$('#YourTextareaID').click(function(e) { e.target.value = ''; })`.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this code,

```
<textarea name="textarea" cols="70" rows="2" class="searchBox" id="textarea" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Please describe why') this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value == '') this.value='Please describe why';">Please describe why</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution if you have dynamic data coming in from a database...
The 'data' variable represents database data.
If there is no data saved yet, the placeholder will show instead.
Once the user starts typing, the placeholder will disappear and they can then enter text.
Hope this helps someone!

```
// If data is NOT saved in the database
if (data == "") {
    var desc_text = "";
    var placeholder = "Please describe why";
// If data IS saved in the database
} else {
    var desc_text = data;
    var placeholder = "";
}

<textarea placeholder="'+placeholder+'">'+desc_text+'</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

No script needed. You can use `onblur` and `onfocus` combined with the `placeholder` to make the text disappear and appear on the **textarea**.

```html
<textarea onblur="this.placeholder='Write something..'" onfocus="this.placeholder=''" placeholder="Write something.." name="" cols="40" rows="4"></textarea>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<textarea onClick="javascript: this.value='';">Please describe why</textarea>
```

Comment: This solution wipes out the text field *every time* the user clicks on it.